# Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, typescript

I have a working Django project and trying to use Angular2 with it. I am new to Angular2. I am getting the following error when I tried to make the routes load from a different file. Also, earlier I have observed that `routerLink` is getting changed to `routerlink` in browser. Is this an expected change?

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined  
        at Object.eval (http://user:8000/ng/src/app/app.route.js:9:16)  
        at eval (http://user:8000/ng/src/app/app.route.js:37:4)  
        at eval (http://user:8000/ng/src/app/app.route.js:38:3)  
        at eval (anonymous)  
    Evaluating http://user:8000/ng/src/app/app.route.js  
    Evaluating http://user:8000/ng/src/main.js  
    Error loading http://user:8000/ng/src/main.js  
(anonymous) @ (index):23  
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232  
Zone.run @ zone.js:114  
(anonymous) @ zone.js:502  
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265  
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154  
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401  
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339
```

I have googled  a lot and found out that this is problem with some versions in angular. So here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
 "name": "angular2-quickstart",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
  "lite": "lite-server",
  "postinstall": "typings install",
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
  "typings": "typings"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
  "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
  "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
  "systemjs": "0.19.27",
  "core-js": "^2.4.0",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
  "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
  "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
  "typescript": "^2.1.5",
  "typings": "^1.0.4",

  "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
  "http-server": "^0.9.0",
  "tslint": "^3.7.4",
  "lodash": "^4.11.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
  "karma": "^0.13.22",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
  "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
  "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
  "protractor": "^3.3.0",
  "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
  }
```

Many errors I faced till now are just due to wrong versions in package.json or npm and node. I have been following a few tutorials and examples where I can learn Angular architecture and syntax but I would appreciate if someone can guide me properly which syntax should be used in which version.

app.route.js:

```
    "use strict";
    var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var module_1 = require();
'@angular/core';
var router_1 = require("@angular/router");
var component1_component_1 = require("./component1.component");
var component2_component_1 = require("./component2.component");
var routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/component1', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'component1', component: component1_component_1.Component1Component },
    { path: 'component2', component: component2_component_1.Component2Component },
];
var AppRoutingModule = (function () {
    function AppRoutingModule() {
    }
    return AppRoutingModule;
}());
AppRoutingModule = __decorate([
    module_1.NgModule({
        imports: [
            router_1.RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
        ],
        exports: [
            router_1.RouterModule
        ]
    })
], AppRoutingModule);
exports.AppRoutingModule = AppRoutingModule;
exports.routingComponents = [component1_component_1.Component1Component, component2_component_1.Component2Component];
//# sourceMappingURL=app.route.js.map
```

Comment: Could you post app.route.js since that's where the error appears to be occurring.

Comment: `....observed that routerLink is getting changed to routerlink...` yes this is an expected change

Comment: @rrd, I have included app.route.js. Do you want to have a look at app.route.ts also ?

Comment: Thanks for the info @PardeepJain.